# ImageView image not appearing in ViewGroup

Tags: android, imageview, viewgroup

I have an `ImageView` as a child of a `ViewGroup` that is part of a `GridView`. The drawable of the `ImageView` does not appear, however I can see the background color, and if I use the drawable in `setBackgroundDrawable` instead, it is displayed. I've tried changing every property and calling `invalidate()` but none have made the drawable appear.

The `Log.i` prints

```
 android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@407bd4c0
```

`setImageResource(int)` doesn't work either.

I'm using Honeycomb.

```
public MyViewGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);

    myImageView = new ImageView(context);
    myImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage);
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    Log.i("",drawable+"");
    //myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
    addView(myImageView);
}
```

I omitted the onLayout code where I call `setLeft()` `setTop()` `setRight()` and `setBottom()`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Update:
Also doesn't work with android.R.drawable images. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is, that you don't set the layout parameters. Try:

```
LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
myImageView .setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I had tried that, also with fixed values. I see the ImageView where I set it, because I can see the backgroundColor, just not the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting getting the image as bitmap, then setting it as drawable.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.myimage)
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);"
 myImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Just out of curiosity: Why you do all of this in your constructor?

Comment: Setting the image drawable from a bitmap didn't work, nor setting the image as the bitmap directly. It is strange because if I add an ImageView to a LinearLayout in the main.xml GUI editor, the image appears fine.

Comment: I do it in the constructor just to make sure it works while I arrange my layout. It will be invisible in the constructor in the final implementation, and the image set when a property is set elsewhere in code.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent layout has width/height of fill_parent, changing it to wrap_content might do the trick.

I was having this problem in Honeycomb using an ImageView with a drawable in a layout - the image was there judging from the width of the dialog I had it appearing in, but I couldn't see the image itself. The ImageView's parent was a LinearLayout with fill_parent. Switching to wrap_content fixed it right up.

Comment: That didn't seem to help, but could be the issue. I had a thought that it might be drawing somewhere outside of the ImageView's bounds. When I set the background color it shows up exactly where I want it, just with no drawable.

The workaround is to use setBackgroundDrawable instead of setImageDrawable or Resource. But then it always stretches to fill, and you lose the scaleType. Since I want to load different drawables with different sizes I can either resize them or the ImageView or deal with the stretching.